# Installing Alien::wxWidgets into a Windows-7/Strawberry-Perl box failed

Tags: perl, wxwidgets, wxperl

I was trying to install `Alien::wxWidgets` on the way to installing Wx.

It failed at the following stage:

```
Fetch failed! HTTP response: 403 Forbidden [403 Forbidden] at inc/My/Build/Base.pm line 305.
Fetch failed! HTTP response: 403 [Forbidden] at inc/My/Build/Base.pm line 305.
Got a '403' from 'prdownloads.sourceforge.net' expected '200' at inc/My/Build/Base.pm line 305.
Unable to fetch archive at inc/My/Build/Base.pm line 307.
Building Alien-wxWidgets
Fetching wxWidgets...
fetching from: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/wxwindows/wxWidgets-3.0.0.tar.bz2
```

A cpan-testers report was filed. You can get it [here](http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/1c5bd90c-6ce1-1014-b463-28475549c6d3)

looking at the cpanm's `work` directory, I saw that such named file was created, but of zero length. I was able though to manually download the said file from this very same URL.

So, how can I *manually* proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `cpanm` will correctly install `Alien-wxWidgets`. To install it manually through `cpan`, do this

- Set the `WXDIR` environment variable to the location of your `wxWidgets` installation
- Enter `cpan` to get a `cpan>` prompt
- Enter `look Alien::wxWidgets` to download and unpack the module, and start a subsidiary command line with the directory containing the unpacked module as your working directory
- Enter the following in order, as described in [the Alien::wxWidgets README](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Alien-wxWidgets/README.txt)

  ```
  perl Build.PL
  perl Build
  perl Build test
  perl Build install
  ```

If you think you may need some esoteric options, then that same README gives all the details you need.

Comment: You are right! I did eventually use `cpan` and it installed all the way to Wx. Thanks!

Comment: @MeirG: I'm glad to help. Out of interest, how did you install the `wxWidgets` DLL? At present I can't get it to build using Strawberry's `dmake`.

Comment: I didn't, `cpan` did :)

Comment: @MeirG: Ah okay. Did you do through the sequence I described above, or did you just do `cpan install Alien::wxWidgets` or something else?

Comment: As you said, just `cpan install Alien::wxWidgets`. I then did 'cpan install Wx' and it all unfolded with a few K of console text that IMHO nobody could decipher.